# Spring data Specification join and group by query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class and need to get the max version of each setting from database.

```
@Table(name = "SETTINGS")
class SettingsEntity {

 String id;
 int version;
 String name;
 boolean is_deleted;

}
```

following is the query that i want to execute

```
Select s.id, s.version, s.name from SETTINGS as s
join (select id, max(version) as version from SETTINGS  group by id) as r
on(s.id = r.id and s.version = r.version) where s.is_deleted = false;
```

I have a specification that needs to run this query.

```
public class SettingsQuerySpec implements Specification<SettingsEntity>
{

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<SettingsEntity> settingsEntityRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder)
    {
      // how to write the query in specification.

    }

}
```

Comment: so what have you got so far?